Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse of Augmented Linear Systems of Equations
The problem I am working on is comprised of $N$ independent system of equations with the same size
$$
A_{4096\times3}x_{3\times1}=b_{4096\times1}
$$
where $x$ has to be found using Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse. I have a loop of $N$ in which I go through each of the systems of equations and find $x_{3\times1}$ and then go to the next $Ax=b$.
We can augment all the systems of equation and stack the coefficient matrices, $A$, and the right hand side vector, $b$, and then solve the resultant equation using Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & A_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & A_N
\end{bmatrix}_{\left(4096\times4096\right) \times 3N} X_{3N \times 1} = \begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
\vdots \\
b_N
\end{bmatrix}_{\left(4096\times4096\right) \times 1} 
$$
My question is will my solution be different than the one found individually? Is this way of solving the problem mathematically incorrect?
